scrapy: return list of relative urls where a where a certain word appears
On this website , there are many cards which are accessible in multiple areas of the site. I am attempting to scrape the site to return all of its instances(in the form of its url) based on the title. For example, a card titled: AZ School Safety program, is found at: https://lawforkids.org/officers & https://lawforkids.org/educators . My goal is for scrapy to do this for me instead of manually finding every instance.
import scrapy

class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = "card"

start_urls = [ 'https://lawforkids.org/',]

def parse(self, response):

for card in response.css('h5.card-title::text').re(r'AZ School Safety Program'): 
yield{
'url': card.css('base::attr(href)').getall()
}

Besides not being confident that url selector is correct, my attempt to crawl results in:
PostsSpider.parse callback is not defined. Any insight is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Your formatting is broken.

Try this approach:
def parse(self, response):
    xp = "//div[@class='card-body']"
    for card in responser.xpath(xp):
        title = card.xpath("normalize-space(./h5[@class='card-title'])").get()
        href = card.xpath(".//a[@class='card-link']/@href").get()
        if href != None:
            href  = response.urljoin(href)
            response.meta['title'] = title
            yield scrapy.Request(href, callback=self.cardpage, meta=response.meta)

def cardpage(self, response):
    print (response.meta['title'])

Try to process individual titles/pages separately, this should help in future processes!

There is no reason to make requests to those links.
